# Magento 2.4.6 Catalog Search result page blank - Impossible to fix?

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, porto-theme

Our catalog search result page has stopped working, it's just a blank page now (almost). Were not sure when or how this happened. We have the *Smartwave Porto* Theme installed, and they say the *catalog search module* is standard Magento, and not related to the theme.

**More information**

- There are no errors in *var/log/** files.
- All layout files are identical on the server and in the downloaded original Porto and Magento packages.
- All modules are enabled.
- We have run *php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy*
- We have run *php bin/magento cache:flush*
- We have compared all files in *vendor/magento/module-catalog-search* with Magento original files.
- We have compared all files in *app/design/frontend/Smartwave/porto/Magento_CatalogSearch* with Port original files.

**Small change found when editing layout file**
If we change from *1column* to *2columns-right* in *app\design\frontend\Smartwave\porto\Magento_CatalogSearch\layout\catalogsearch_result_index.xml* the text "Filtrera" appears on the white blank page (see image above).

Anyone have the slightest idea what could cause this?

Thank you,

Comment: Check magento log files

Comment: @MPRaj Nothing there to see, no errors at all, superstrange!!

Comment: @Aknot first check via applying magento default theme, If the issue still exists and check elastic search working properly.

Comment: This could be a PHP error, so check the server logs (from the root, usually /var/log/php[version]-fpm.log , **not magento logs**). Try enabling developer mode. Try checking the page rendering via xDebug. Since this happens during the filter rendering stage, check the status of your search engine (usually elasticksearch or openserach: `sudo systemctl status opensearch` or `sudo systemctl status elasticsearch`).

Answer (score 0):

Do a view-source for that page in your browser.
You're missing all your asssets (css/js) for that page.

HTH, Tom

Comment: Yes I saw that too, strange, feels like the error occurs earlier than the Magento_CatalogSearch module, don't you think?